# sending file by C++

Tags: c++, c, network-programming, network-protocols

I want to send a file in C++ over network (for a chat program)
what should I do?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2014033/send-file-in-socket-programing-in-linux-with-c-c

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html . The Iostreams example should give you the first good step. Asio is a portable network library of the boost project. Boost is available for most platforms available today.

You can stream in the file and stream out it into the TCP stream.

Answer (score 1):

Use Open source FTP library for more robust application .Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/259166/good-free-ftp-client-library-for-windows-c-commercial-apps) thread for c++ based open soruce library.

Comment: I couldn't disagree more. FTP has a lot of inherent problems (especially nowadays with all the NATs in the way) and certainly should be avoided for new applications.

Answer (score 1):

Its quite easy.  Set up a TCP/IP socket and then split the file into packets and send them across.  TCP is reliable thus all the packets will arrive in the right order and it will handle re-transmission etc.

If, however, you need to use an unreliable transport (such as UDP) then look at [stop and wait](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stop-and-wait_ARQ) (Easiest), [go-back-n](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Go-Back-N_ARQ) or [selective repeat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selective_Repeat_ARQ) (Which are both somewhat harder but far more efficient).

Answer (score 0):

You can open a direct connection between the two and send the content the file. For that, one side will be the client and the other will be the sender.

You can see a simple implementation [here](http://www.pcs.cnu.edu/~dgame/sockets/sockets.html).

Answer (score 0):

You will be doing something called socket programming. Please refer [Beej's Guide to Networking](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/) for all the details and the solution to your problem.