# Implementing a Network Stream for FTPClient from a Read buffer(VC++)

Tags: visual-c++, ftp, network-programming

I have implemented a read/write stream to read a buffer, manipulate the data(like adding headers and footers during output file creation) and write it to a file. What should I do to instead of writing to a file locally, to write to a file in a remote location, but I have only FTP access to the remote server.

I wrote a client using POCO to transfer the file to the ftp server, but it is a two step process. How can I implement a solution which directly writes to the FTP server? I am not able to get how to connect a source stream(which is actually a ReadFile call) to the FTP network stream?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an FTP client library that you can call directly from your app, to avoid the need to write the file to disk and then send it via a separate process.

[This earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/259166/good-free-ftp-client-library-for-windows-c-commercial-apps) has some useful info.