# Is there a library to parse output from an FTP LIST command?

Tags: c++, c, parsing, ftp

I am using libcURL to get a list of directories on an FTP server. The problem is that FTP's `LIST` command's output is not well defined and it differs per server.

Is there a free library that parses common formats? It has to work on Mac OS X.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1244095/c-ftp-library http://stackoverflow.com/questions/259166/good-free-ftp-client-library-for-windows-c-commercial-apps http://cr.yp.to/ftpparse.html ... That's from 30 seconds on Google. Did you look into any of those?

Comment: @derobert I tried Googling but I couldn't find those. I'll take a look at ftpparse.

Comment: I googled for: `ftp LIST library` to find ftpparse.

Answer (score 1):

Many servers nowadays support the `MLSD` and `MLST` commands (see [RFC 3659](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3659.txt) Section 7), which have well-defined responses to address this very issue.  You should use those before falling back to the old `LIST` command.

There are a LOT of `LIST` formats still being used online.  Though not a solution for your particular project, [Indy](http://www.indyproject.org) implements several dozen parsers in its library, so I know it is not a simple task to support `LIST` very easily.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned you can used the MLSD FTP command to get the formatted listing output (RFC 3659 Section 7).
To do this, add the following call to your curl_'s:

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST , "MLSD");
```

The output will then be something like that:

```
type=file;modify=20130319142533;size=8; EXAMPLE.txt
```

As you can see there are `key=value;` pairs that can be parsed easily.